# New computer freezes permanently when running Access-VBA Script

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an extensive VBA Script in Excel which separates an Access-Table into several Excel-Files and conducts a number of formatting and calculations in Excel. The tables have a few hundred lines, I loop through the whole table repeatedly and some of the excel calculations use SUMIF functions etc. and therefore take a while to calculate.

The Script is not optimized in terms of performance but used to finish on my old Dualcore Win10 32Bit (German version with English language pack) Notebook within 10 minutes.

I upgraded to a newer notebook (Win10 English version, 64 Bit, i5 Quadcore), but when I try to run the same script using the same Access file the notebook freezes permanently. I can't even abort the script and after waiting 1+ hour it isn't finished yet and I have to hard-reset my computer.

Is there some windows system level setting I might have missed to adjust? Whenever I go back to my old notebook using the same files/scripts it runs without problems.

Comment: Can you identify which part of your code is responsible for the drop in performance?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: What version (2010, 2013, 2016) of Office old vs new? Obviously old machine used 32bit Office. Does new machine also have 32bit? Or did you install 64bit? Try going back to 32bit as there is no reason to use 64bit.

Comment: Things to try: Put a `DoEvents` in your loop. If you have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, comment it out - perhaps there is a problem that isn't displayed because of it.